# Фоновое видео YouTube на сайте

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, вёрстка, видео

Сделал на сайте фоновое видео с YouTube, используя плагин jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js.

Все работает, но в консоли почему-то целая куча ошибок появилась, на демо сайте (http://pavel.shimansky.ru/videobackground) тоже много ошибок.

Может быть кто-то знает с чем это может быть связано и возможно ли это исправить? Спасибо

Comment: Чтобы получить ответ, не плохо было больше конкретики, а не абстракции...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделай без плагинов, так проще! Используйте iframe от youtube, отключите видимость кнопок, и css'ом разместите видео под блоком.

Comment: @Иван Чабан, можно и так, но тогда вопрос как сделать чтобы фоновое видео было полностью по всей секции, размер которой может быть разный, в том числе и на адаптиве. То есть, например, как для фоновой картинки задаем background-size: cover; и такое же сделать для iframe от youtube, чтобы пропорции видео сохранялись, но при этом оно полностью покрывало фон секции?